# A single `make` prerequisite having a target names many times repeated

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Why in a single `make` prerequisite consist of many targets names, if there's a target name being listed more than once i.e. repeatedly, only the first will get processed while the next is to be ignored/skipped, how to have that repeated target name in that prerequisite all are to be processed ?

Answer (score 0):

When you have many files as prerequisites of your default rule it means that it will check if the these files are up to date BEFORE running its recipe.

It means that if you have other rules in your makefile that ha the files that are prerequisite of your default rule as TARGETS it will run them before and when all the prerequisites are generated and up to date it will finally run your default recipe.